# How can I mix different data types in props array of a component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling with understanding how I can pass several different data types as props to a child component. I have an object and two strings that I would like to pass as props from the parent to the child component.

**This is how I want to pass the props from the parent component to the child component prov-activity:**

```
<prov-activity :activity="{{$activity}}" :apikey="     
{{$apikey}}" :geocodelink="
{{$geocodelink}}"></prov-activity>
```

**This is how the child component receives the props:**

```
props: [{ 'activity' : Boolean }, 'googlemapsapikey', 'googlemapsgeocodelink']
```

Activity is an object, whereas the other two are strings passed as props.

The warning message I receive now is the following:

```
[Vue warn]: props must be strings when using array syntax.
```

And it seems the activity is not being passed properly anymore, as I receive this error as well:

```
Property or method "activity" is not defined on the instance but  
referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either 
in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

How do I define the props array properly so that I can get the object and the two strings into my child component???

I know I can simply do this props:[ 'activity', 'geocodelink', 'apikey' ], however, out of some other code logic, I need to preserve the 'activity' as a type Boolean, so how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use either the array syntax or the object syntax to define the props, you can't combine both. In this case, you want to use [the object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation).

Your props should look like this.

```
props: {
  activity: Boolean,
  googlemapsapikey: String,
  googlemapsgeocodelink: String
}
```

Comment: Mixed prop syntax support was added https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1798